# Vscode open file with showTextDocument at specified line

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want my extension to be able to open a document at a certain line. Is there a way to expand the code below to have the file open with the cursor at say **line 10, column 4?** I've seen how this is done with a hyperlink, but I was wondering if there's a way to navigate to the file within the extension.

```
var openPath = vscode.Uri.file(filePath);
vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(openPath).then(doc => {
     vscode.window.showTextDocument(doc);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@ddavid456 had most of the answer I needed, and when I added one more line to the block below, I got the entire functionality I needed.

```
var pos1 = new vscode.Position(10,4);
var openPath = vscode.Uri.file(filePath);
vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(openPath).then(doc => 
{
    vscode.window.showTextDocument(doc).then(editor => 
    {
        // Line added - by having a selection at the same position twice, the cursor jumps there
        editor.selections = [new vscode.Selection(pos1,pos1)]; 

        // And the visible range jumps there too
        var range = new vscode.Range(pos1, pos1);
        editor.revealRange(range);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Possibly something like this, where this is a fixed value, but you can pass in or calculate a range and reveal the position.

```
var openPath = vscode.Uri.file(filePath);
vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(openPath).then(doc => {
vscode.window.showTextDocument(doc).then(editor => {
    var range = new vscode.Range(new vscode.Position(10, 4), new vscode.Position(11, 0));
    editor.revealRange(range);
   })
});
```

Comment: This opened the file in the general area of the range, but is there a way to put the cursor there too, or have the range be selected?

Comment: Placing the cursor not sure but having the range selected you can. `editor.selection = new vscode.Selection(range.start, range.end);` right before revealRange

Comment: There is an options parameter for `showTextDocument`.